# Variable in return does not get correct value from API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a problem. I'm calling an API to check if the user is logged in or not. Unfortunately the `isAuthenticated.current ? ...` wont take the value from the API call.
I looked at [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) , but it didn't work. The `console.log(isAuthenticated.current )` give me the right output. But if `isAuthenticated` is `true` the return don't take me to the right page it always redirect me to `login`. Before `useRef(false)` I tried that with `const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] ...`

```
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {

       // const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
        //var isAuthenticated = null;
        const isAuthenticated = useRef(false)
        useEffect(() => {
            checkLoginStatus()
        }, []);

    const checkLoginStatus = () => {
        axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/session/extend`, { withCredentials: true })
            .then(response => {
                isAuthenticated.current = true;
                console.log(isAuthenticated.current )
 
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                isAuthenticated.current = false;
            });
    };


    return (
        <Route
            {...restOfProps}
            render={(props) =>
                isAuthenticated.current ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
        />
    );


}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Editor from "./pages/Editor";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/auth/ProtectedRoute"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/editor" component={Editor} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login is calling the `/editor`

Answer (score 0):

Mutating a ref doesn't trigger a re-render.

When a change needs to trigger a re-render, set a state with the change instead.

Comment: I had before this `const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);` but that also didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you are actually calling `setIsAuthenticated`, then it should do, but you need to provide an [mcve] of that attempt before anyone can help you debug it.

Comment: Oh. You need three states: Loading, Authenticated, Not Authenticated. With your current binary, a default of `false` it is just going to hit the redirect before the Ajax request has changed the state.

Comment: thank you. What should be look like the  three states?

Comment: Still: Loading, Authenticated, Not Authenticated as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: `const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false); const [isNotAuthenticated, setIsNotAuthenticated] = useState(false); ... .then(response => { isAuthenticated(true) }) .catch((error) => { setIsNotAuthenticated(true) });` something like that?

Comment: No. `const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState("loading");`

Comment: Could you please be so kind and show me what you mean ? How to get the running code ;'/

Answer (score -2):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  //var isAuthenticated = null;
  //const isAuthenticated = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginStatus();
  }, []);

  const checkLoginStatus = () => {
    setIsLoaded(false);
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/session/extend`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);

        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        // console.log(isAuthenticated.current )
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);

        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      });
  };

  if (isLoaded === false) {
    return <h1> Loading... </h1>;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...restOfProps}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
}
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: That didn't work :/ `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.